# jacocoTestReport task failed with error: malformed input off : 17, length : 1

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

I have a problem with task `:jacocoTestReport`. `gradle clean build` task for my Gradle Java project (Spring Boot) failed with error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jacocoTestReport'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: malformed input off : 17, length : 1
```

I have `chcp1251` archives files in my test resource and resource folders:
[image: image with project structure]

And I think it's cause of jacoco task failed, but I'm my not sure. Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "idea"
    id "groovy"
    id "jacoco"

...

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test

    reports {
        html.enabled false
        xml.enabled true
    }
}
```

Can you help me with this problem, please? Maybe I cant set charset for jacoco?

Answer (score 0):

jacoco doesn't support encoding not in `UTF-8`. I recreate my archive in test resource folder with new name without spaces and cyrillic symbols. And it's works fine.

Update (2023-02-26). Also I removed my `chcp1251` files from build in `build.gradle` via:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            exclude '**/*.edt' // file extension of my `chcp1251` archives
        }
    }
}
```